# Word-initial or -initially?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Quoting from OUP blog ([+](https://blog.oup.com/2011/11/sugar/)):

> As noted above, sure and sugar are such conspicuous monsters because
>   word initially su– designates sh only in those two words.

According to oxforddictionaries.com website ([+](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/word-initially)), *word-initially* is an adverb. However, it seems to me that an adjective is the right choice to modify the noun *su-* in the above-mentioned sentence. Is that correct?

Comment: Regarding the adj/adv. distinction, here is another, though different, question (also by me!): [Unusual or Unusually?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429928/unusual-or-unusually) on ES with a good answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Word initially” functions as an adverb modifying the following clause. It is no incorrect to use an adverb here (although I guess it might be possible to punctuate it differently).